# Ubuntu Virtualbox screen unsuable

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox

I'm trying to boot the Ubuntu iso on virtual machine installed with Win 7 on virtualbox and I have a graphics error making the screen unusable.

[image]

I tried to change several settings in virtualbox but nothing works.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.

Hit these keys: `right-control`-F1, then `right-control`-F7 to fix your display.